# What are these CAN frames / messages?

Tags: can

I'm writing software for a project that sends data to me using a CAN bus. The software runs fine in small test scenarios with 3-4 bus members, however with increasing members the bus sends data with very high addresses and new (non hexadecimal) data I haven't seen before:

*First and last 4 frames for reference*

```
(1541503830.323881) can0 011#008955EA0AC30AC8
(1541503830.412314) can0 030#0A770A8E00100000
(1541503830.412758) can0 61F#0A770A8E00100000
(1541503830.413049) can0 69F#0A770A8E00100000
(1541503830.413889) can0 **00C480A7**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.414182) can0 **09014E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.414464) can0 **029D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.414753) can0 **1A7D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.415040) can0 **1A7D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.415329) can0 **1A7D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.415618) can0 **1A7D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.415904) can0 **1A7D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.416192) can0 **1A7D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.416475) can0 **1A7D3E9F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.416764) can0 **1D3E9F0F**#0A770A8E54707FF3
(1541503830.417872) can0 030#0A770A8E0FF30FF5
(1541503830.466440) can0 031#0A7D54580A8E0A99
(1541503830.514830) can0 008#0000000000000000
(1541503830.520243) can0 032#0000000000000000
```

Here I see way too high addresses. Other unknown data:

```
(1541503837.081060) can0 020#0AC20AF90AE10ACC
(1541503837.081271) can0 020#0AC20AF90AE10ACC
(1541503837.081478) can0 020#0AC20AF90AE10ACC
(1541503837.081689) can0 020#0AC20AF90AE10ACC
(1541503837.082138) can0 448#**R4**
(1541503837.133876) can0 01F#**R4**
(1541503837.135442) can0 03C#0AC20AF9
(1541503837.135886) can0 0DF#0AC20AF9
(1541503837.136202) can0 75F#0AC20AF9
(1541503837.136781) can0 65F#0AC20AF9
```

I don't think `0x448` is used by us, also non hexadecimal data?
I need a direction to work on, am I looking at faulty hardware, or are these specifics of the CAN protocol I'm not yet aware off?

The data was logged using `candump -L can0` on Linux, socket can as driver and a standalone MCP2515 as CAN interface, connected via SPI. The other members also use the MCP2515 however directly soldered on PCB.

Additional data logged with `candump -e -d can0`:

```
can0  02F   [8]  00 04 00 FA 00 02 00 00
can0  010   [8]  0A BA 0A F3 0A D8 0A CD
can0  011   [8]  00 88 55 C1 0A B6 0A AC
can0  012   [8]  00 01 00 02 00 10 00 00
can0  08812DD7   [8]  remote request
can0  1FF7D75F   [8]  remote request
can0  1EFAEBFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FFBFBDF   [8]  remote request
can0  0FEF7FFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1BFFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FEFFDFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FF7FFFF   [8]  remote request
can0  1FFFFFFF   [8]  remote request
can0       008   [8]  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
can0       009   [8]  00 00 00 00 02 58 00 00
can0       00F   [8]  00 04 00 00 00 10 00 00
can0       030   [8]  0A 71 0A 82 0F F4 0F F1
-- snip --
can0       02F   [8]  00 04 00 FA 00 02 00 00
can0       010   [8]  0A B4 0A F3 0A D6 0A CD
can0       011   [8]  00 89 55 A8 0A B5 0A A5
can0       012   [8]  00 01 00 02 00 10 00 00
can0  1FFFFFFF   [8]  remote request
can0       5BD   [1]  remote request
can0       6DF   [1]  remote request
can0       008   [8]  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
can0       009   [8]  00 00 00 00 02 58 00 00
can0       00F   [8]  00 04 00 00 00 10 00 00
can0       030   [8]  0A 8C 0A 91 0F F0 0F F2
```

Comment: I hope this is somewhat on topic here, I wouldn't know which other site would be better fitting

Comment: How much do you trust your MCP2515 CAN interface? If you see a message nobody's supposed to send, I would double check the traffic with a reliable data logger.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev valid point, I just would like to make sure I'm not overlooking something CAN specific before sending the electric engineer on it

Comment: You didn't say how you run `candump`, but if you suspect bus congestion, I'd run it with `-e` and `-d` flags to see error frames and dropped frames, respectively.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev thanks for that info, I also added data logged with `-e` and `-d`. I think I'll request some data logged with a reliable data logger.

Comment: The "R4" looks more like something generated by the tools (candump.)  A quick look at the code doesn't show where it could be generated, but my phone isn't the best for viewing code - maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see looks like [remote frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Remote_frame): it's a feature of the CAN bus which allows to transmit certain frames on request rather than periodically. Simply put, a regular frame is transmitted by a single node, first ID, then length, then data. With a remote frame, the node which wants the data transmits the frame ID and length plus a special bit (RTR), and waits for the node which handles that frame to transmit the actual data.

`448#**R4**` means that a node has requested the remote frame with ID of 448 and DLC of 4, but nobody on the bus volunteered to supply the data.

Comment: That's a starter, thanks! Do you know anything about those oddly long addresses as seen in the first block? Or are these related to the remote frames too?

Comment: @Kimmax No, those look like extended frame format addresses, with 29 bits instead of 11.